# Spring 4 Dynamic Bean Creation

Tags: java, spring

Maybe I'm not using the right terminology and that's why i can't find an answer, but I want to know how can I take information from a database to create beans that I can inject into the application?

Here's an example, rather than having this coded in a configuration file, I would like to possibly loop some values stored in a database and build these beans based on that:

```
@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean factory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
    factory.setStartDelay(3000);
    factory.setCronExpression("0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *");
    return factory;
}
```

How can I build beans like this and have them become a part of the application?

Comment: [SpringCloudConfig](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) does something similar, loads config properties from a database-like server at startup.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably multiple ways how to achieve that, but all of them are pretty complex with a lots of pitfalls. I would say that in your example you should not create triggers as separate beans but rather have a single service to manage your schedules (and leave it out of Spring).

The thing with Spring is, that it is not designed to act as a dynamic container (like OSGi for example). This means that for example `@Autowired` dependencies are initialized during context startup and stays the same till the application context is destroyed.

However it is possible to construct bean definitions on the fly during initialization. Best place would be [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html). But this would be called during context initialization. This means you will have no other beans available (like `EntityManager`, `DataSource`, ...).

Another possibility is to somehow take advantage of context hierarchy. You can create and destroy application contexts on-the-fly. However implementing that would require deeper knowledge of Spring's internals.

---

Question for others: not sure if it is possible to reference initialized beans from parent context during child context initialization.

Answer (score 0):

After you load the necessary bean properties from Database , use [BeanDefinitionBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.html). You can refer [this link](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-beandefinitionbuilder.html)